Transparent / Absolute Canvas above animation causes GPU glitches
I made a small one pager which uses framer for scroll animations. I wanted to add a small smoke effect when scrolling past over a certain section.
The overall effect seems to function but it wrecks the whole sites performance on chrome.
It runs smooth on Firefox so it almost seems as if chrome doesn't use hardware acceleration.
Here is the scrolling animation on chrome

and on firefox

Please see this page on Firefox vs Chrome:
https://ghettogoethe-git-feat-smoke-c5h8nnao4s-projects.vercel.app?_vercel_share=1mwhvH8awz6k9zTbbQ1FWuNAwWjZ0Dw3
My Chrome GPU settings say the following

Sometimes it runs smooth on Chrome, but 95% it lags and glitches and is almost unusable.
Fix:
Setting the ANGLE graphics backend to D3D11on12 fixes the issue.

How can I make sure this runs smoothly on all Chrome browsers regardless of this setting?

All browsers look the same to me - perhaps your chrome, as you say, doesn't use GPU for some reason

See chrome://gpu/ (which SO doesn't recognise as a url, so copy+paste to chrome address bar)

@fdomn-m Thanks, I was looking for that. However it seems GPU is supported and HA is enabled :/
